# Jquery edit content from wysiwyg to iframe element

Tags: jquery, iframe

I need to be able to do the following:

1. click on the `<span class="editable">` element contained in the iframe.
2. a popup with a TinyMCE wysiwyg comes up. content from the iframe "editable" element gets loaded into TinyMCE. I edit the content then hit save button.
3. New edited content gets updated on the iframe.

So far i have this (which works)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#template").contents().find(".editable").bind("click", function () {
        // get content of clicked item and insert it into wysiwyg
        $('#wysiwyg').html($(this).html());

        // give this element myedit id (this is so that I know which element i'm editing)
        $(this).attr('id', 'myedit');
    });

    // Wysiwyg
    $('#save').click(function () {
        // find element that i'm editing and update it's content with new content from wysiwyg
        $("#template").contents().find("#myedit").html($('#wysiwyg').html());

        // remove editid
        $("#template").contents().find("#myedit").attr('id', '');
        return false;
    });


});
```

question:
How would i do this without assigning myedit id back and forth? and just simply using $(this) somehow? so i would know that when finished editing $(this) would be updated with the new content.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the `$(this)` issue, you could do `$(this).data('calledFrom',$(this));` and then referencing to it in the second `.click()` function: `$('#wysiwyg').data('calledFrom').html($('#wysiwyg').html());`

Code for option 1:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#template").contents().find(".editable").bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // get content of clicked item and insert it into wysiwyg
    $('#wysiwyg').html($(this).html());

    // give this element myedit id (this is so that I know which element i'm editing)
    $(this).data('calledFrom', $(this));
  });

  // Wysiwyg
  $('#save').click(function (e) {
    // find element that i'm editing and update it's content with new content from wysiwyg
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#wysiwyg').data('calledFrom').html($('#wysiwyg').html());

    return false;
  });

});
```

Option 2 (putting it all in one function):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#template").contents().find(".editable").bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    // get content of clicked item and insert it into wysiwyg
    $('#wysiwyg').html( $this.html() );
    $('#save').bind('click',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).unbind('click');
      $this.html($('#wysiwyg').html());
    });
  });
});
```

Shorter, but less readable.

Not sure if this helps, but I hope it will!

P.S. always use `e.preventDefault()` instead or as well in your functions as it is supported by newer, more popular browsers

Comment: I'm sorry but i still can't figure this out: $(this).data('calledFrom',$(this)); can You please post all of the code. please :) as far as the other method it doesn't update the <span tag> after clicking 'save. thanks so much!

Comment: i tried this:                 $("#template").contents().find(".editable").bind("click", function () {
                    $('#wysiwyg').html($(this).html());
                    $(this).data('calledFrom', $(this));
                });

                // Wysiwyg
                $('#save').click(function () {
                    $('#wysiwyg').data('calledFrom').html($('#wysiwyg').html());
                    return false;
                });   which didn't work :(

Comment: Sure, I will edit it now. I wasn't on the computer when you commented.